# C# Error when attempting to pass Type as parameter when method requires a type

Tags: c#, methods, types, parameters

As a test case Ive created the following very simple method:

```
public static object TestMethod(Type t)
    {
        return t;
    }
```

For the type I am attempting to pass through it, I have created a very basic class also as a test:

```
public class TestClass
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Finally I am attempting to call the method normally:

```
TestClass sample = TestMethod(TestClass);
```

However it seems that when TestClass is passed as a parameter for `TestMethod`, I receive the error: "'TestClass' is a type, which is not valid in the given context."

This makes no sense to me as the parameter required IS a type.

Comment: typeof or GetType() will work, but the better question is what exactly are you trying to accomplish?  This seems like a prime opportunity for generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use your method, do it like this

```
TestClass sample = (TestClass)TestMethod(typeof(TestClass));
```

Your Result will be an **Type** and not `TestClass` so you will get a RuntimeException.

On already existing instances use

```
TestMethod(testClassInstance.GetType())
```

But what are your trying to achieve?

Comment: @MachineLearning the last line of this answer is the important point here.  There are almost definitely better ways of achieving what it seems OP is trying to do.

Comment: Touche, but do you know what technical debt is? ;)

Comment: @lokusking The end goal was to pass in a json string and a class full of properties in which I deserialize the json string and fill the class with the appropriate values from a response of the API I am calling

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp

Comment: @JSArrakis pls, consider editing your question if you need to better clarify it...

Comment: @MachineLearning My question was answered. My deserialization was not the question, only why when passing a Type I was receiving an error. The scope of the question was simply that, and it was answered. I am not looking for a better way to do the rest of the method that I am writing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TestClass sample = (TestClass)TestMethod(typeof(TestClass)); //notice the cast because the method is returning an object
```

### Technical debt

The above compiles **but** throws an invalid cast exception: what a senior *professional* should tell you is that you need to change *also* this

```
public static object TestMethod(Type t)
{
    return Activator.CreateInstance(t); 
}
```